# Is there a way to mass convert leads into accounts and contacts using data loader?

Tags: leads

Is there a way to mass convert leads into accounts and contacts using data loader?
I have 2400 leads which are already present in SFDC.
don't want to use code.
Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Dataloader only supports basic DML operation, you cannot use it to convert to leads as it requires additional information while conversion and convert lead operation is not supported by dataloader.

You can maybe write a batch apex with `Database.convertLead` or try some appexchange package.

Answer (score 0):

A very reliable although not cheap option is ['ZaapIT'](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/appxListingDetail?listingId=a0N30000009uXwyEAE), but it's going to be around $700 a year as you need the 'premium' version and they sell a minimum of 2 user licenses.

A cheaper option although only compatible with Lightning environments is ['Multiple Lead Converter'](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/appxListingDetail?listingId=a0N3A00000EJdWcUAL).

Another option is '[Bulk Object Field Creator](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/appxlistingdetail?listingId=a0N30000000qDqqEAE)' which is cheap and does seem to work in both classic and lightning environments.

Answer (score -1):

Try This app,
[Mass Convert Lead](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000004g33vEAA)

Comment: Not been updated in years / not available any more.